# Proving that f(x)=||x-a|| is a convex function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

f(**x**)=||**x**-**a**||, where **a**=(0,1)^T

Can someone show why f(**x**) is convex?

Comment: Could you do the same if it were $f(x) = \|x\|$ instead?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show your attempts at demonstrating this, otherwise the question will likely be closed.

Comment: Norms are convex because they are subadditive and positive homogenous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}$ for $\vec x, \vec y \in X$ and $\tau \in [0,1]$ that

\begin{align}
f((1-\tau)\vec x + \tau \vec y) &= \|(1-\tau) \vec x + \tau \vec y - \vec a \| \\
&= \| (1-\tau) (\vec x - \vec a) + \tau (\vec y - \vec a)\| \\
&\leq \|(1-\tau)(\vec x - \vec a)\| + \|\tau(\vec y - \vec a)\| \\
&= (1-\tau) \|\vec x - \vec a\| + \tau \| \vec y - \vec a \| \\
&= (1-\tau) f(\vec x) + \tau f(\vec y).
\end{align}